# How to select a cell that contains certain string and number?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have a dataframe that includes strings, ints and floats. To sum up, it looks something like this:

| Date | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 | Col 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09/2023 | 181.70 | 17.70 / 22.22 | 14.40 | 109.00 | NaN | 6 | 0 / NTD |
| 06/2023 | 143.60 | 17.00 | 15.30 | 190.05 | NaN | 6 / 11.41 | 1 |
| 03/2023 | 5 / 18.68 | NC / 17.67 | NC / 30.02 | NaN | NaN | 5 / NTD | NC / 2 |

For each row, I'm trying to apply 3 conditionals:

1. if the cell contains ***number / number***, replace that within same df for the text "Division"
2. if the cell contains ***NC / number***, replace that within same df for the text "No changes"
3. if the cell contains ***number / NTD***, replace that within same df for the text "No ToDo's"

Note that everything will be in the same dataframe, that's just changing the text for the conditions that the code must detect. That said, this should be the expected output:

| Date | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 | Col 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09/2023 | 181.70 | Division | 14.40 | 109.00 | NaN | 6 | No ToDo's |
| 06/2023 | 143.60 | 17.00 | 15.30 | 190.05 | NaN | Division | 1 |
| 03/2023 | Division | No changes | No changes | NaN | NaN | No ToDo's | No changes |

My attempt for one of them (condition # 2):

```
 for k in range(0, df.shape[1]):>   
             for m,p in enumerate(df[df.columns[(k)]]):  
                    if (p == ("<NC> / ")):
                         df[df.columns[k]][m] = df[df.columns[k]][m].replace(p, 'No changes')
```

Similarly, I applied the above code for the '`number / NTD`' (condition #3) and seems to doing well, however, **the condition # 1** has been slightly complicated because it **needs to be the first one stated in the code (not in the else part of the if condition)** and I don't know how to apply the 'if' condition for any number that's before and after the '/'

Any help on that will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Pandas' [regex match](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html) and [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
pattern1 = df.apply(lambda column: column.str.match(r'([0-9\.]+)\s*/ ([0-9\.]+)'))
pattern2 = df.apply(lambda column: column.str.match(r'NC\s*/ ([0-9\.]+)'))
pattern3 = df.apply(lambda column: column.str.match(r'([0-9\.]+)\s*/ NTD'))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.select([pattern1, pattern2, pattern3], 
                            ['Division', 'No Change', 'No ToDo\'s'], df), 
                  columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
```

Output:

```
      Date     Col 1      Col 2      Col 3  Col 3 .1 Col 4      Col 5       Col 6
0  09/2023    181.70    Division     14.40   109.00    NaN          6   No ToDo's
1  06/2023    143.60      17.00      15.30   190.05    NaN    Division          1
2  03/2023   Division  No Change  No Change     NaN    NaN   No ToDo's  No Change
```

---

Update: Just use `replace`:

```
df = df.replace({r'([0-9\.]+)\s*/ ([0-9\.]+)': 'Division', 
                 r'NC\s*/ ([0-9\.]+)': 'No Change',
                 r'([0-9\.]+)\s*/ NTD': 'No ToDo\'s'
                }, regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! :) Been trying to implement it but I keep getting the error: TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray

Have any suggestion on how to deal with it? Been trying few things but no changes yet

Comment: Try `print(pattern1)` to see what you get

Comment: All three patterns work like a charm. In my case, for the first method, the error keeps popping up.

The last edit with the replace function is doing the job, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the pair `X(0) / Y(1)`, build a [`case_when`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.case_when.html) and  [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) the original dataframe :

```
ext = df.astype(str).stack().str.extract(r"(.+) / (.+)").dropna()

tpl = (
    pd.Series(index=ext.index)
    .case_when(
        [
            (ext.apply(lambda s: s.str.match("[\d.]+")).all(axis=1), "Division"),
            (ext[0].eq("NC") & ext[1].str.match("[\d.]+"), "No changes"),
            (ext[0].str.match("[\d.]+") & ext[1].eq("NTD"), "No ToDo's"),
        ]
    )
)

df.update(tpl.unstack())
```

Output :

```
      Date     Col 1       Col 2       Col 3   Col 4  Col 5      Col 6       Col 7
0  09/2023    181.70    Division       14.40  109.00    NaN          6   No ToDo's
1  06/2023    143.60       17.00       15.30  190.05    NaN   Division           1
2  03/2023  Division  No changes  No changes     NaN    NaN  No ToDo's  No changes
```